# ListView select row

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an ArrayAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)LayoutInflater.from(context);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.consumerlist_row, null);
        }

        SharedClass.GenericItem item = SharedClass.consumerList.get(position); 

        if (item != null) {

            final GenericItem fitem = item; 
            v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int id = ID = ((ExtEditText)v.findViewById(R.id.dayreadout_entry)).getIdentifyingNumber();
                    if(prevID!=ID){
                        if(!((ExtEditText)v.findViewById(R.id.dayreadout_entry)).isSelected()
                            &&!((ExtEditText)v.findViewById(R.id.nightreadout_entry)).isSelected()){


                            if(fitem.GetIdAddress()==ID){  
//Set unique identificator of 
                                ((ExtEditText)v.findViewById(R.id.dayreadout_entry)).setChosen(true);
                                TransitionDrawable drawable = (TransitionDrawable) v.getBackground();                                                                   
                                drawable.startTransition(animSpeed);
                            }

                            if(prevID!=-1){
                                CloseEditMode();                                    
                                LeaveRow(prevRow, prevID);                                      
                            }
                            prevRow = v;
                            prevID=ID;                              
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
 SetColorToRow( v, item);       
        return v;
}
```

LeaveRow:

```
private void LeaveRow(View row, int id){    
    int ids = ((ExtEditText)row.findViewById(R.id.dayreadout_entry)).getIdentifyingNumber();
    if(id==ids){
    SharedClass.GenericItem item = GetItemByID(id);
    ((ExtEditText)row.findViewById(R.id.dayreadout_entry)).setChosen(false);                

            TransitionDrawable tDrawable = (TransitionDrawable)row.getBackground();                             
            tDrawable.reverseTransition(animSpeed); 
}

}
```

SetColorToRow:

```
private void SetColorToRow(View v, GenericItem item){

    boolean ids = ((ExtEditText)v.findViewById(R.id.dayreadout_entry)).isChosen();

    String day = String.valueOf(item.GetDay()); 
    String night = String.valueOf(item.GetNight());
    String skipped = String.valueOf(item.GetSkipped());

    if(day.equals("-9999999")&&night.equals("-9999999")&&!skipped.equals("0")){
        if(ids){
            TransitionDrawable td = (TransitionDrawable) v.getBackground();
            td.startTransition(animSpeed);
        }
        else
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listviewitem_yellow_blue);           
    }
    else if(day.equals("-9999999")&&night.equals("-9999999")&&skipped.equals("0")){
        if(ids){
            TransitionDrawable td = (TransitionDrawable) v.getBackground();
            td.startTransition(animSpeed);
        }
        else
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listviewitem_white_blue);                        
    }
    else {
        if(ids) {
            TransitionDrawable td = (TransitionDrawable) v.getBackground();
            td.startTransition(animSpeed);
        }
        else
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listviewitem_green_blue);                        
    }

 }
```

The problem is when I select a row(the row turns blue color) and move list down(when the row disappear) it selects other rows. Seems it copies row's state and put it in the list below.

```
 --------REAL SELECTED ROW--------

 ---------------------------------
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |          LIST VIEW            |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |                               |
 |-----WRONG SELECTED ROW--------|
 |                               |
 ---------------------------------
```

What am I doing wrong? Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found adding a field to the adapter to work for this:

```
    private int selectedIndex;
    public void setSelectedIndex(int index){
          this.selectedIndex = index;
    }
    //Your activity or controller can access this index at any time. 
    public int getSelectedIndex(){return selectedIndex;}
```

In the public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

```
    if(selectedIndex == position){
          convertView.setBackground(R.id.some_resource_selectable);
    }else{
     //set background null
           convertView.setBackground(null);
    }
```

Then on my listview on item click listener

```
     onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
```

Hope this helps